# Objective-C - Instruments shows leak for array, even with ARC

Tags: objective-c, xcode, memory-leaks

The following function shows a leak in Instrument (Leak) - Xcode, even with the code commented out as shown below.

```
void function () {
    NSArray *devices = [AVCaptureDevice devices];

    // I have used devices here..but I commented to check leak.
    devices = nil;
}
```

Responsible library is AVFoundation. I'm using ARC.

Comment: Can you show more code please so we can help?

Comment: The edit tells us nothing more. What are you doing with `devices`? what are you doing with objects in the array?

Comment: @Abizern I have not used devices, I commented out for testing purpose, still the leak found. I have kept only above two lines.

Answer (score 1):

Instruments doesn't show where objects are being leaked - it shows where the object that is being leaked is being **created**.

What you can do is to look at how you manage the memory of `devices` and make sure that you are releasing it correctly.

It's odd that it's showing a leak under ARC - so it would be useful to see some relevant code to see what is being done.

Comment: When my application is launched this fun is getting called, and I commented out everything in this function except this lines, leaks found. Any idea?